# How can I import Listview items C#

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview in a Form2 and now I want that the items in this Listview are the same as in the Listview in Form1. Is there anything like:

```
listview1.Items = Form1.listview1.Items
```

Comment: No. You would move them. If you want to copy them you need to create them anew with the data they hold. But you could create a datasource and have both LVs use it.

Comment: And how can I create a datasource?

Comment: I was not right wrt simply creating and sharing a datasource. LVs don't do that out of the box. Also note that any ListViewItem can only be member in __one__ items collection, so all other answers are wrong, afaiks..

Comment: Consider using VB.NET, that kind of statement actually works.  Learning object-oriented programming is a speed-bump on any programmer's learning curve.  There is no shortcut, the brain transplant is always slow and painful.  You'll get there, eventually, without our help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Items` property as a whole is read-only. So your code doesn't compile.

And a `ListViewItem` can only be part in **one** `ListViewItemCollection`. So code that tries to add all the Items to the second `ListView` will fail at runtime. But you can create clones of the Items..

If you just want a **copy** of the `Items` you can do this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
            listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)lvi.Clone());
```

Or using LINQ, which is is usually a bit shorter:

```
listView2.Items.AddRange(listView1.Items.Cast <ListViewItem>()
                                        .Select(x => (ListViewItem)x.Clone())
                                        .ToArray());
```

This time LINQ takes in fact **longer** to write with its casting than the simple loop..

Note that `Clone` can only create 'shallow' copies. This means that while the value types, like all the string properties get copied into new, independent strings, the copy's reference properties only contain copies of the reference, so they still point to the same object. So if you add a `Tag` to a `ListViewItem A` that refers to another `Item B`, the cloned `Item C` will point to `Item B` as well..

Probably not an issue, but important to keep in mind..

`ListView` is not good at `DataBinding`. So if you want to actually **share** the same data you either need to write code that synchronizes the LVs or look into projects that add data binding to a LV subclass like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10008/Data-binding-a-ListView).

Also note that you obviously need to have a reference to both of the two `ListViews`. Passing either the `Control` you want to access or a reference to the whole `Form` in the constructor is one common way to do that. In the latter case don't forget to make the modifier `public`! - For these techniques there are nearly 23 trillion answers around here ;-)

Comment: Note the simplified updated answers using the Clone method!

Answer (score -1):

you can make listview1 a static member so that you can access it that way:

```
public static ListView listview1 {get; set;}
```

and in the constructor you can set your ListView to it :

```
public Form1()
{
   listview1 = this.YourListView;
}
```

Edit :

i am not sure if you can do this:
   listview2.items = listview1.items;

but you can loop through each item in listview1 and add it to listview2

Answer (score -1):

As long as they are of the same type, it's very simple with AddRange:

list2.AddRange(list1);